# Populate field in Jarray

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a json object like this. I want to populate the sourceSerialNumber in the device object in C#.net. Right now I have a dynamic object like  componentConfig.Config.deviceConfig.device , however i am unable to access the sourceSerialNumber field. How do I acheive this?

```
{{
  "id": "ember10085",
  "device": [

  "contactlessEnabled": true,
  "dccTimeoutSecs": 3,
  "debitKeyIndex": 0,
  "defaultLanguage": "eng",
  "deviceType": "Ingenico iPP320 RBA",

  "googleSecrets": "",
  "lineLength": 20,

  "sourceSerialNumber": "",
  "taskDesc": "Station1",
  "terminalList": "01",
  "threadType": 1078,
  "tip": {
    "enabled": true,
    "presetMode": "Percent",
    "percent1": 15,
    "percent2": 18,
    "percent3": 0,
    "percent4": 0,
    "amount1": 20,
    "amount2": 40,
    "amount3": 0,
    "amount4": 0
     }
   }
  ]
}}
```

Comment: 1. Deserialize to a concrete object. 2. Change `sourceSerialNumber` value.

Comment: You wrote, * i am unable to access the sourceSerialNumber field.*  Please share the current code that does not work.  A [mcve] would be ideal.  Note that your JSON does not look well-formed, it is surrounded by an extra set of braces `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always going to be same, create an ValueObject type (not an entity) to mimic it.
Then use it while deserializing the response via Json.net

```
MyValueObject obj = JsonConvert.Convert<MyValueObject>(response) ;

Obj.propertyName = newValue;
```